# Calling Custom Options menu when webview is running

Tags: android, android-webview, android-menu

I want to call my function onCreateOptionsMenu when the menu button is clicked when my webview is running. Right now when you click the Memnu button when the Webview is runing it displays some default menu not my custom menu.

How would I modify my code below to disable the default menu and display my custom menu? When the web view is not running it shows my custom menu when you click the menu button.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity mActivity = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // SETS DEFAULT MODE TO LANDSCAPE
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
            Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://Google.com");

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                mActivity.setTitle("Google.com");
                mActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) { 
        // do your menu stuff here 

        return true; 
    } 
        else 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    } 


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the onKeyDown function, to intercept the Menu key. Otherwise the webview will consume it. Something like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // do your menu stuff here

        return true;
    }
        else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Is there even a keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU Button Type? I get Red Underlines when i use that code.

Comment: I edited my Code block with your snipet in it. It now disables my custom Menu when the web view is not running. When the web view is running it still displays some default menu. Not the One i created.

Comment: I assumed that the webview covered the whole screen. If that is not the case, you will have to call the setOnKeyDown method of the webview instead. You may also have to override some other methods of the webview, or you may prefer to just shift the focus.

Comment: Hmm well maybe thats my problem its not covering the whole page? IDK. When i hit the back button it unloads the web page. But it does not shut down the app. only when i hit the back button and then the menu will my costom menu display. Im lost.... Thanks for trying to help